# Python: Refer to objects dynamically

Tags: python

Apologies if this is a silly question.

I have a list of potential dictionary keys here:

```
 form_fields = ['sex',
                'birth',
                'location',
                'politics']
```

I am currently manually adding values to these keys like so:

```
        self.participant.vars["sex"] =  [Constants.fields_dict["sex"][0], Constants.fields_dict["sex"][1], self.player.name]
        self.participant.vars["birth"] = [Constants.fields_dict["birth"][0], Constants.fields_dict["birth"][1],self.player.age]
        self.participant.vars["location"] = [Constants.fields_dict["location"][0], Constants.fields_dict["location"][1],self.player.politics]
```

I'd like to be able to do a use a for loop to do this all at once like so:

```
for i in form_fields:
    self.participant.vars[i] =  [Constants.fields_dict[i][0], Constants.fields_dict[i][1], self.player.`i`]
```

Obviously, however, I can't reference the object self.player.`i` like that.  Is there a way to reference that object dynamically?

Comment: Your attributes don't match the dict keys: `Constants.fields_dict["sex"][1], self.player.name` (`sex` and `name`). Is that a mistake?

Comment: Wow.  Thank you.  You just identified a bug that has been plaguing me for a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.

```
for i in form_fields:
    self.participant.vars[i] =  [Constants.fields_dict[i][0], Constants.fields_dict[i][1], getattr(self.player, i)]
```

Comment: Ah, perfect.  Thanks Ding.  Didn't know about this

Comment: @Parseltongue Np, glad it helps! :)